# Can't get role with discord.js

Tags: javascript, api, debugging, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot with `discord.js`. The code below is supposed to give a selected user a certain role.

```
const roleTag = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '<role name>');
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
member.roles.add(role);
```

But every time I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

---

Note: The message object has no problem (I checked it)

Comment: Well you claim that message object has no problem, however it seems like you are not getting message.guild. This code snippet is a little too short, can you show how do you get/initialize the message object?

Comment: If nothing is wrong with the `message` object, the problem might be that you are sending the message in a `dm`, thus `message.guild` returning undefined.

Comment: Does `member` return correctly? (`console.log(member)` to have a look).

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the error, in the add function or defining roleTag? Btw, you are bot adding the defined role, you are adding *role* and you have it named *roleTag*